# how to detect when a price higher than previous high

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to find when a price value is cross above a high, I can find the high but when I compare it to current price it gives me all 1
my code :

```
peak = df[(df[‘price’] > df[‘price’].shift(-1)) & (df[‘price’] > df[‘price’].shift(1))]
df[‘peak’] = peak
df[‘breakout’] = df[‘price’] > df[‘peak’]
print(df)
```

out :

|  | price | peak | breakout |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | NaN | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | NaN | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | NaN | 1 |
| 4 | 5 | NaN | 1 |
| 5 | 6 | 6.0 | 1 |
| 6 | 5 | NaN | 1 |
| 7 | 4 | NaN | 1 |
| 8 | 3 | NaN | 1 |
| 9 | 12 | 12.0 | 1 |
| 10 | 10 | NaN | 1 |
| 11 | 50 | NaN | 1 |
| 12 | 100 | NaN | 1 |
| 13 | 110 | 110 | 1 |
| 14 | 84 | NaN | 1 |

expect:

|  | price | peak | high | breakout |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | NaN | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | NaN | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | NaN | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 | NaN | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 6 | 6.0 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 5 | NaN | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 4 | NaN | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 3 | NaN | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 12 | 12.0 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | 10 | NaN | 0 | 0 |
| 11 | 50 | NaN | 0 | 1 |
| 12 | 100 | NaN | 0 | 1 |
| 13 | 110 | 110 | 1 | 1 |
| 14 | 84 | NaN | 0 | 0 |

with fillna :

```
 price   peak   look  breakout
0       2    NaN    NaN     False
1       4    NaN    NaN     False
2       5    NaN    NaN     False
3       6    6.0    6.0     False
4       5    NaN    6.0     False
5       4    NaN    6.0     False
6       3    NaN    6.0     False
7      12   12.0   12.0     False  ----> this should be True because it it higher than 6  and it also the high for shift(-1) and shift(1)
8      10    NaN   12.0     False
9      50    NaN   12.0      True
10    100  100.0  100.0     False
11     40    NaN  100.0     False
12     45   45.0   45.0     False
13     30    NaN   45.0     False
14    200    NaN   45.0      True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df["breakout"] =  df["price"] >= df["peak"].fillna(method = "ffill")
```

If you want it with 1s and 0s add the line:

```
df["breakout"] = df["breakout"].replace([True, False],[1,0])
```

Note that `df["peak"].fillna(method = "ffill")` returns:

```
0       NaN
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       NaN
4       6.0
5       6.0
6       6.0
7       6.0
8      12.0
9      12.0
10     12.0
11     12.0
12    110.0
13    110.0
Name: peak, dtype: float64
```

So you can compare it easily with the price column.